# VirtualBox guest hangs when starting vbox additions

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have a Fedora 14. I installed the Ubuntu 11.04 i386 mini.iso in Virtualbox. After install when I reboot it, and wanted to start it:

[image]

it just hangs...for minutes... what can I do?

Comment: Does it work without the VirtualBox Additions?

Comment: omg..there were virtualbox packages in the mini.iso...:O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get purge virtualbox*
```

solved the problem